# Can I run a receptacle from a GFCI in the bathroom to another room?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Can I run a receptacle  from a gfci  in the bathroom to another room?
Is this allowed? I know it would work, just looking to see if this falls under the electrical code?

Comment: AFIK the current NEC prohibits this. A GFCI protected  receptacle in a bathroom cannot be on a circuit with receptacles not in that bathroom or in other bathrooms. However, the lights and exhaust fan can be on a circuit with lights or receptacles in rooms other than a bathroom.

Answer (score 2):

The bathroom needs its own circuit, the only current code compliant way to go to another room if it is also a bathroom. Added per @harpers comment. If the bathroom loads include the fan and light then another bathroom can not be powered from this circuit. I like bathroom lighting to be separate because if the wife or girls plug in a curling iron and use a hair dryer at the same time it may trip the circuit and put them in the dark.

Comment: True, though also...If the circuit powers bathroom non-receptacle loads (lamp, fan) then it cannot power receptacles in other bathrooms.

Comment: This is correct I will add that.+